# What's the mac software or plugin for filters like those?

Tags: color-correction, filter

I was wondering what software do the professionals use to apply filters like [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoLTPcD1S4Q).

Modern series like the ones Netflix is making are another example that use those kind of nice movie filters.

So if u guys could help me, what's a good software, and how to apply this kind of stuff, filters, color corrections, etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you be more specific as to which effect as your question is very board

Comment: Color correction, and color changing, in general, I'm just making simple non professional vídeos of a band playing, and wanted to give it a nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

Colour correction is a field that people devote their [entire careers](https://www.shootonline.com/news/editing-sound-vfx-color-grading-nominees-set-hpa-awards) to. What makes you think it is as simple as applying a "nice movie filter"? Insulting, much?

That video looks good because it was shot by a skilled cinematographer, with good lighting, good art direction, good editing and good colour grading, as well as some judicious use of effects like the video scan lines which may indeed have been a filter. The fact that the acting and direction are good helps too, though it's the look we're discussing here.

If you want to recreate that kind of look I'd suggest you

- become (or hire someone who is) a skilled cinematographer. Should be doable in somewhere between [ten years to a lifetime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvA93wEu_8E), the best ones are learning until they retire.
- become (or hire someone who is) a skilled art director. Once again anywhere up to a lifetime should be enough
- become or hire someone… etc. etc.

Comment: I'm don't think I'm insulting anyone by asking in which program this kind of stuff is made. I'm also not saying that my filter would get as nice and well polished as theirs (it could take a hundred years for someone to be professional, that was not my question). Maybe I don't know the exact terms, but I just wanted to know a good software, where these "EFFECTS", not to say filter than, are made.

Answer (score 0):

Final Cut Pro X includes colour correction and grading tools, as do After Effects and the free Da Vinci Resolve.